# How to (configure) send mail using content pages in umbraco 7?

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7, umbraco6, umbraco-blog

I am working on Umbraco project,i want to implement functionality like sending email using gmail.
I known how to implement it using c# code but i don't know how to configure it dynamically by adding content pages in umbraco.

Anyone have idea about this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to listen to the events of your interest and execute your code to send the email. For details on events supported by umbraco check out https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Events/